# How can I change function execution to another output

Tags: c++, debugging

I am working on some homework on debugging a given program. We are to enter input and see if the program gives expected output, if not go into code and see what we can do to change the code to get output. I believe to found the error not giving input I will paste below and if needed any more of the code to help solve it.

```
// Function to calculate the total medals

int totalMedals(Country countries[]) {
    int total = 0;

    // Loop to calculate the total medals

    for (int i = 0; i < numCountries; i++) {
        total += countries[i].gold + countries[i].silver + countries[i].bronze;
    }
    return total;
}

// Function to find the country with the most medals

int mostTotalMedals(Country countries[]) {
    int index = 0;

    // Loop to find the country with the most gold medals

    for (int i = 0; i < numCountries; i++) {
        if (countries[i].gold > countries[index].gold) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
```

it has to be in the function to find the most medals instead of getting total gold it needs total medals. How should that function be re written in order to show the total medals instead of total gold medals. If that makes sense?

Comment: Well, how would you do this if you were not a computer, and you had a list of all the medals? You'd probably add up all the medals for a country, and then see if that's larger than any other country you've calculated so far.

Comment: You already know how to get the total medals for one country, it's `countries[i].gold + countries[i].silver + countries[i].bronze`.

Comment: // Show the country with the most medals
    int mostTotal = mostTotalMedals(countries);
    cout << "Country with the most total medals: " << countries[mostTotal].name
         << endl;    is how it is called to be said for the output. So does that function not need to exist anymore? the one causing the showing of most gold instead of most medals

Comment: Please [edit] your question when you need to add additional details. Code in comments is very hard to read aside from short, single-line excerpts.

Comment: Unrelated: Look into [range-based `for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to simplify your code a bit.

Comment: Side note: Get rid of that C-style array and use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the all code and the all question so I'm guessing a bit.
My guess that the try to find the country with the most medals.
One more thing, the code look like C and not C++, so I will answer like C.
The country code:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int gold;
    unsigned int silver;
    unsigned int bronze;
} Country;
```

I added a function to get medals for one country:

```
int getContryTotalMedals(const Country *contry) {
    return (contry->gold + contry->silver + contry->bronze);
}
```

and the function should be this:

```
// Function to find the country with the most medals
int mostTotalMedals(Country countries[], int numCountries) {
    int index = 0;
    int totalMedal = getContryTotalMedals(countries + index);
    int currentTotal = 0;
    // Loop to find the country with the most gold medals
    for (int i=0; i < numCountries; i++) {
        currentTotal = getContryTotalMedals(countries + i);
        if (currentTotal > totalMedal) {
            index = i;
            totalMedal = currentTotal;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```